# If-else not executing block when bool is true?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, boolean, nslog

This could just as easily be something stupid I missed, but take a look at this code: (which has been stripped down to just debug functionality, although the actual method name was left unchanged)

```
-(BOOL)shouldHideStatusBarItem:(BOOL)showItem{

if (showItem == YES) {
    NSBeep();
    NSLog(showItem ? @"YES(inloop)" : @"NO(inloop)" );
}
else if (showItem == NO){
    NSBeep();
    NSLog(showItem ? @"YES(inloop)" : @"NO(inloop)" );
}

NSLog(showItem ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
return showItem;
}
```

When I pass in YES it logs:

```
YES
```

When I pass in NO it logs:

```
 NO(inloop)
 NO
```

Obviously when I pass in YES it SHOULD log:

```
YES(inloop)
YES
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Which did you pass, YES or an integer value to the method ? I think you might pass a integer value which is not 1.

Comment: Are you sure you passed `YES`? `BOOL` is just a typedef for `signed char`, so there's nothing preventing you from passing a value outside the range `0, 1`. Everything that's not `0` will be treated as truthy by the ternary operator, but it won't be `== TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to just check the truth of the `showItem` variable. The `BOOL` type is not actually restricted to the values `YES` and `NO`.

```
if (showItem)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Details: `BOOL` is `typedef`ed to a `signed char`, so it could potentially be values other than `YES` (1) and `NO` (0).

Comment: Oh, I get it-- all nonzero values are true! Ahah.

Comment: @PopKernel all nonzero values except of `YES` are illegal for a `BOOL`.

Comment: Then how could it be true but not == YES?

Comment: Possibly by "illegal" @AminNegm-Awad means "you *shouldn't* do that". Because it clearly is possible for a `BOOL` to contain values other than `YES` or `NO` (after all, it's an 8-bit type - not 1-bit).

Comment: Yes, it should be true, if none puts in something else than { `YES`, `NO` }. Sometimes this happens, because it works in C. What I wanted to say: It is not wrong to test against `YES`, but it is wrong to put something else in than `YES` or `NO`. For all scalar types it is pretty easy to store illegal values (= leading to undefined behavior). The problem is not to compare such an object against one of its legal values, but to put an illegal value in it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico This is an *implementation detail*, that *will change* very soon. Some of the "do not compare to `YES`" guys will get some surprise in the next months.

I do not know, what happens if a `BOOL` stores other values than { `YES', `NO`}, because it is documented, that it can only store `YES` or `NO`. Every assumptions about the behavior outside these values are in the neverland between praying and believing.

Answer (score 0):

a variation on lakesh's answer

```
-(BOOL)shouldHideStatusBarItem:(BOOL)showItem{

    if (showItem) {  

    } else {

    }

    NSBeep();

    NSLog(showItem ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
    return showItem;
}
```